# Alternative to .readLine() / readLine only returns lists

Tags: java, eclipse, bufferedreader, readline, wikimedia-dumps

I'm using read line to get some text from wikipedia. But read line only returns lists, not the text that I want. Is there any way to use an alternative or to solve my problem?

```
public class mediawiki {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL yahoo = new URL(
            "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Jesus&action=raw"
        );
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(yahoo.openStream())
        );
        String inputLine;       

        //http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Space&action=raw

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String TEST = in.readLine();

            //while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            //System.out.println(inputLine);
            //This basicly reads each line, using
            //the read line command to progress

            WikiModel wikiModel = new WikiModel(
                "http://www.mywiki.com/wiki/${image}",
                "http://www.mywiki.com/wiki/${title}"
            );
            String plainStr = wikiModel.render(
                new PlainTextConverter(),
                TEST
            );
            System.out.print(plainStr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'readline only returns lists'?  Read line returns a string for each line in that the reader encounters.

Comment: What is your `PlainTextConverter` and your `WikiModel`? These are not part of the standard platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `readLine()` on a `BufferedReader` instance [definitely returns a String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29). In your code example, you are doing readLine() twice in your while loop. First you store it in `inputLine`:

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
```

Then you are storing (the *next* line) in `TEST` without checking if it is `null`. Try to pass `inputLine` instead of `TEST` to the `render` method.